# Graph stack bar for multiple variables with wrong percentages

Tags: r, ggplot2, reshape, geom-bar

I am trying to get a graph stack bar for multiples variables to display percentages for each level in each variable, example:

```
Category  <- c(rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), times = 4))
Country  <- c(rep(c("Country A", "Country B", "Country C", "Country D", "Country F", "Country G"), times = 16))
Data      <- data.frame(Category, Country)

ggplot(Data,aes(x=factor(""),fill=factor(Category)))+
  geom_bar(position="fill")+
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(..count../sum(..count..))), stat='count',position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))
```

percentages ok

[image]

Now I reshape my data frame, but lamentably I could not get the result expected, graph drisplay wrong percentages:

```
library(tidyr)
dflong= gather(Data, variable, freq)

ggplot(dflong,aes(x=factor(variable),fill=factor(freq)))+
  geom_bar(aes(x=factor(variable)),position="fill")+
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(..count../sum(..count..))), stat='count',position=position_fill(vjust=0.5))
```

wrong percentages

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pre-calculate the percentages before plotting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dflong %>%
  count(variable, freq, name = 'percentage') %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(percentage = prop.table(percentage) * 100) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(variable, percentage, fill = freq, 
                 label = paste0(round(percentage,2), '%')) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_text(position=position_stack(vjust=0.5))
```

[image]